# Python won't write to the SQL table that I've created, instead it creates another one

Tags: python, sql, azure, pyodbc

I'm trying to have my code upload a DataFrame to a table that I've already created in a SQL database.

However, instead of writing to that table it creates another one with the same name but some extra string of text.

the table is **[Database].[dbo].[myTable]**

the table that the code creates is **[Database].[dbo].[DIR\User.myTable]**

Here's the code, it has worked in the past so I'm not sure what the issue can be now

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; Trusted_Connection=yes; Server='servername005.azr.com, DATABASE=Database; application intent=readwrite'
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_str, fast_executemany=True)
df.to_sql("myTable", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=True)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried to explictly set the schema to "dbo"? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One user above solved it! I'm not sure if I can mark his/her comment as solved but here's what worked. Adding schema="dbo" to the to_sql method.

Thanks!

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; 
Trusted_Connection=yes; Server='servername005.azr.com, DATABASE=Database; application intent=readwrite'
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_str, fast_executemany=True)
df.to_sql("myTable", con=engine, if_exists='replace', schema="dbo" index=True)
```